# Python Observer Pattern with *args not working

Tags: python, design-patterns, observable

i've encountered an issue while trying to implement the Observable Pattern in python. He is my code :

```
class Observer:
    """
    Classe destinée à définir les modalités d'observation des évènements
    """
    _observers = []

    def __init__(self):
        self._observers.append(self)
        self._observables = {}


    def observe(self, event_name, callback):
        self._observables[event_name] = callback


class Event():
    """
    Liste des évènements observables
    """

    def __init__(self, name, *args, autofire = True):
        self.name = name
        # self.data = [arg1, arg2]
        self.arg = [a for a in args]
        # self.arg = args
        # self.arg2 = arg2
        if autofire:
            self.fire()

    def fire(self):
        print(self.arg)
        for observer in Observer._observers:
            if self.name in observer._observables:
                observer._observables[self.name](self.arg)


class Room(Observer):

    """ Test de l'observation d'un évènement"""

    def __init__(self):
        Observer.__init__(self) # Observer's init needs to be called
        print("La chambre est prête.")

    def someone_arrived(self, who, place):
        print(who, "est arrivé à", place, "!")


def main():
    room = Room()
    room.observe("someone arrived",  room.someone_arrived)

    Event("someone arrived", "Tof", "Toulouse")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The issue lies in the `__init__` function from the `Event()` class. When i try to pass multiple arguments with `*args`, it always get me back issues, whereas when i only put `args` all works fine.

If someone could try it and give me back something to look at or explain me why it bugs, it'd be appreciated !

Thanks !

Comment: _"When i try to pass multiple arguments with *args, it always get me back issues"_ - you should write in the question what kind if "issues" you have with that.

Comment: BTW, note that the observer pattern has to sides: the object being observed (aka Observable) and the object which observes it (aka Observer). The Observable object contains a list of observers. In your case Observer contains a list of observers, which makes no sense.

Comment: Well, looking at your code, the problem (as of now) seem to be, that you have list of remaining positional arguments (you could have left them as a `tuple` for that matter, or `list(args)` yields the same result as that comprehension) and pass them as such (as single argument) to `observer._observables[self.name](self.arg)` -> being `Room().someone_arrived()` and hence needing two arguments. Long story short, if you unpack them by doing `observer._observables[self.name](*self.arg)`, it'd appear to work fine.